# brightcove player, manually choose what rendition to play

Tags: javascript, api, media-player, brightcove

I want to determine what rendition to play from brightcove, i know that brightcove choose it automatically by bandwidth or frame loss, i want to choose what rendition to play. I need to implement this using javascript, there are more APIs in the site but i dont know how to know the `src` so that i can reference it properly to my code.

I'm looking at [http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/selecting-multi-bitrate-streaming-renditions#examples](http://support.brightcove.com/en/video-cloud/docs/selecting-multi-bitrate-streaming-renditions)

from where i am, i can't even reference this function to be called at my script

```
setRenditionSelectionCallback(callback:Function)
```

if possible can you guys give me actual working codes or examples that i can study or use.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

"Populates a ComboBox in BEML named "renditionCombo", displaying various choices for rendition quality selection."

https://github.com/BrightcoveOS/Rendition-Selector-Plugin